# Will it be complicated to use Gauss's Law in this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

> The electric field strength depends only on the $x$ and $y$ coordinates according to the law $\vec{E}=a(x\hat{i}+y\hat{j})/(x^2+y^2)$ where $a$ is a constant.
>   Find the flux of the vector$\vec{E}$ through the closed surface $x^4+y^4+z^4=81$.

I used integral form of Gauss's Law to solve this question but the integration was very complicated. I took the direction normal of the surface by taking out its gradient. Then I did surface integral.

If this would be a sphere, it would be very easy in doing surface integral. So how do I do this? Is there any other method?

Comment: Do you know how the surface looks like?

Comment: Divergence of E is coming out to be zero.

Comment: The equation of the surface is not of a sphere and nor does it relate to any other surface so I don't know how the surface looks like.

Comment: If the divergence is zero means the field is solenoidal. And yes I am familiar with the divergence theorem.

Comment: [See what WolframAlpha comes up with?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%2By%5E4%2Bz%5E4%3D81)

Comment: @Farcher I can't understand the plot by wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
**Hint :**

The surface is as in the picture. Accidentally the electric field is that produced by the infinite $z-$axis with uniform linear charge density $\lambda$. So, it would be interesting  to compare your result with that applying Gauss's Law for the charge on the $z-$axis from $z=-3$ to $z=+3$. Note that it's not necessary to find the flux through the given surface but you can use another more convenient surface (sphere or cube or cylinder for example) with proven equal flux value.